# LeetCode: Burst Balloons C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/

> Given `n` balloons, indexed from `0` to `n-1`, each balloon is painted with
>   a number on it represented by array `nums`. You are asked to burst all
>   the balloons. If you burst balloon `i`, the number of coins you will get is calculated as:
>   $$ nums[left] * nums[i] * nums[right] $$Here, `left` and `right` are adjacent indices of `i`. After the burst, `left` and `right` then becomes adjacent.
>
> Find the maximum coins you can collect by bursting the balloons
>   wisely.
>
> Note:
>
> You may imagine $$ nums[-1] = nums[n] = 1 $$They are not real therefore
>   you can not burst them. 0 ≤ `n` ≤ 500, 0 ≤ `nums[i]` ≤ 100
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> Input: [3,1,5,8]
> Output: 167 
> Explanation: nums = [3,1,5,8] --> [3,5,8] -->   [3,8]   -->  [8]  --> []
>              coins =  3*1*5      +  3*5*8    +  1*3*8      + 1*8*1   = 167
> ```

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace RecurssionQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class BurstBalloonsTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestExample()
        {
            int[] nums = {3, 1, 5, 8};
            BurstBalloonsClass burst = new BurstBalloonsClass();
            Assert.AreEqual(167, burst.MaxCoins(nums));
        }
    }

    public class BurstBalloonsClass
    {

        public int MaxCoins(int[] nums)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[nums.Length +2];  // we add 2 because of the question
            // nums[-1] = nums[n] = 1
            int n = 1;
            foreach (var x in nums)
            {
                if (x > 0) // we care only about positive values for profit
                {
                    numbers[n++] = x;
                }
            }
            numbers[0] = numbers[n++] = 1;
            int[][] memo = new int[n][];
            for (var index = 0; index < memo.Length; index++)
            {
                memo[index]= new int[n];
            }
            // we allocate NxN matrix for memoization

            return Burst(memo, numbers, 0, n - 1);
        }

        private int Burst(int[][] memo, int[] numbers, int left, int right)
        {
            if (left + 1 == right)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (memo[left][right] > 0)
            {
                return memo[left][right];
            }

            int ans = 0;
            // we try all the options between left and right
            // we compare the answers of all of the options and the maxmial one
            // if poped all of the ballons from left to u and from i to right we have only an option to pop
            // numbers[left] * numbers[i] * numbers[right]
            for (int i = left + 1; i < right; ++i)
            {
                ans = Math.Max(ans, numbers[left] * numbers[i] * numbers[right]
                                    + Burst(memo, numbers, left, i)
                                    + Burst(memo, numbers, i, right));
            }

            memo[left][right] = ans;
            return ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things come to mind when I read your code.

There is a nice feature on arrays in C# called `CopyTo()`. It gives you the possibility to copy an array without using a loop. Like so:

```
int[] newNums = new int[n];
nums.CopyTo(newNums, 1); 
newNums[0] = newNums[n-1] = 1; //This line I really like.
```

There is also something called a multidimensional Array which basically does the same thing as `int[][]`. This gives you the possibility to do this:

```
int[,] memo = new int[n,n];
```

Use them together and you can remove all your loops from `int maxcoins`.

Regarding your actual work method Burst I would say that you make things rather confusing. When debugging, the first thing that happens is that you cache a number series which is not allowed until 3 balloons are popped. It adds [0]*[1]*[5] to the cache. A more reasonable approach would have been [0]*[1]*[2] then [0]*[1]*[3] up to [0]*[1]*[5]. After that switch to [0]*[2]*[3] etc.  When you reach [0]*[4]*[5] you start over at [1]*[2]*[3].

To do that you would have to create nested loops in your `Burst` method:

```
        for (int i = left+1; i < right; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j<= right; ++j)
                ans = Math.Max(ans, numbers[left] * numbers[i] * numbers[j]
                                + Burst(memo, numbers, left, i)
                                + Burst(memo, numbers, i, j));
        }
```

However, there is an even more simple approach to this problem and that is to actually pop the balloons in the array. This can be done easiest with a list instead of an array. But both are possible. So what you would do is to create a new set of balloons after each pop. So here caching is out of the question because you never really know what range you processed before. And to be honest I guess it would most likely slow down the process and make the code harder to read. I use the same variable names as you but in reality I would name `nums` and `numbers` as `balloons` and `newNumbers` would be named `remainingBalloons`. I did however change the variable `i` to `baloonToPop` to make it easier to understand what it represents. I left the adding of the ones in the code because it simplifies the Burst method.

```
    public void MaxCoins(List<int> nums)
    {
        nums.Insert(0, 1); //Add the ones to the array
        nums.Add(1);
        int result = Burst(nums);
    }

    private int Burst(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int baloonToPop = 1; baloonToPop < numbers.Count-1; baloonToPop++)
        {
            List<int> newNumbers = new List<int>();
            newNumbers.AddRange(numbers);
            newNumbers.RemoveAt(baloonToPop);
            int sumFromBaloonPop = numbers[baloonToPop - 1] * numbers[baloonToPop] * numbers[baloonToPop + 1];
            result = Math.Max(result, Burst(newNumbers) + sumFromBaloonPop);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

To do it with an array (in case there is a library restriction) you would have to create a new `Array` and then copy `Subranges` from the initial one instead of creating a copy of the `List` using `AddRange + RemoveAt` as above:

```
int[] newNumbers = new int[numbers.Length-1];
Array.ConstrainedCopy(numbers, 0, newNumbers, 0, baloonToPop);
Array.ConstrainedCopy(numbers, baloonToPop + 1, newNumbers, baloonToPop, numbers.Length - (baloonToPop + 1));
```

Comment: Thorough review, have some rep from me :)

Comment: @dfhwze I didn't understand why you put a bounty on my question, but thanks you and thank you guys for the reviews

Answer (score 4):

The comment here

```
int[] numbers = new int[nums.Length +2];  // we add 2 because of the question
```

is not really useful, it requires to read the entire question to figure out why 2 is added to the number of balloons. I would suggest something like

```
// Allocate array for all balloons, plus the two "imaginary" balloons 
// at positions -1 and n.
```

which closely matches the note from the problem description:

> You may imagine nums[-1] = nums[n] = 1. They are not real therefore you can not burst them.